# How to evaluate this indefinite integral $\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1+\mathrm{e}^x}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

One of my student asked me to help her evaluate this indefinite integral $$\int\dfrac{\cos x}{1+e^x}\mathrm{d}x,$$
and I tried several minutes, but at last I had to given up, for I thought that  it is very possible the primitive of $\dfrac{\cos x }{1+e^x}$ can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions. And then, I resorted to Maple and  Mathematica. But these two computer algebra systems can not give me the answer, which shows that it is very certain that that indefinite integral is irreducible. But since I am not very familiar with differential Galois theory, I do hot know how to tell my student?  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Another way to ask this question, is to ask which functions cannot be integrated?

Comment: You may suggest that it is a difficult question, and this advanced theory is to find for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075296/72361

Comment: @Don : I do not understand the motivation behind making this question as a duplicate. Also, why are we marking duplicates to duplicates? I have travelled through one too many a Duplicaception tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$\int e^{-kx}\cos x\,dx = \frac{\sin x - k\cos x}{(1+k^2)\,e^{kx}}$$
we just have:
$$\int\frac{\cos x}{1+e^x}\,dx = \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\sin x - k\cos x}{(1+k^2)\,e^{kx}}.$$

Comment: Further explanation could be nice :)

Comment: @Nick: the first formula follows from integration by parts and the second one by expressing $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ as $e^{-x}-e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}-\ldots$.